# Java Spring how to getmapping with name

Tags: java, spring-mvc

how can I make @getmapping without id and by (String) name .....

@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")

```
Employee one(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the same way you already are but switch out id with name

```
@GetMapping("/employees/{name}")

Employee one(@PathVariable String name) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: how can i make my own FindByName method